# Win10 SysPrep ERROR: Failed DeleteInstance AntiSpywareProduct.instanceGuid

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, imaging

After tons of AppX and "Tile Data Model Server" service headaches, I've now found this in our Windows 10 (Enterprise) SysPrep logs:

`ERROR: Failed DeleteInstance AntiSpywareProduct.instanceGuid{GUID}`

We have paid support with Trend Micro so I opened a case with them. They just told me to add exceptions for C:\Windows\System32\SysPrep\SysPrep.exe

Not believing this was enough, I also closed Trend Micro before attempting to SysPrep...but it still failed. 
However, after I uninstalled Trend Micro, **SysPrep succeeded**....but this isn't an ideal solution.

Am I stuck without AV in our image or there any way around this?

Comment: If I had this to do over: hold the vendor's feet to the fire and make them provide a solution or workaround.